# How to scrape price from booking.com using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape price from booking.com but not successful. Any suggestions

My code as follows

```
#Importing necessary library

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time
import re
import requests
from itertools import zip_longest
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


price = []


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEM2AEB6AEB-AELiAIBqAIDuALnhOzyBcACAQ&lang=en-gb&sid=422b3ff3c0e98b522259ad1cad2505ea&sb=1&src=searchresults&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Fsearchresults.en-gb.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEM2AEB6AEB-AELiAIBqAIDuALnhOzyBcACAQ%3Bsid%3D422b3ff3c0e98b522259ad1cad2505ea%3Btmpl%3Dsearchresults%3Bclass_interval%3D1%3Bdest_id%3D-1506909%3Bdest_type%3Dcity%3Bdtdisc%3D0%3Bfrom_sf%3D1%3Bgroup_adults%3D2%3Bgroup_children%3D0%3Binac%3D0%3Bindex_postcard%3D0%3Blabel_click%3Dundef%3Bno_rooms%3D1%3Boffset%3D0%3Bpostcard%3D0%3Braw_dest_type%3Dcity%3Broom1%3DA%252CA%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%3Bshw_aparth%3D1%3Bslp_r_match%3D0%3Bsrc%3Dindex%3Bsrc_elem%3Dsb%3Bsrpvid%3D912403b6d1220012%3Bss%3DAuckland%3Bss_all%3D0%3Bssb%3Dempty%3Bsshis%3D0%3Bssne%3DAuckland%3Bssne_untouched%3DAuckland%3Btop_ufis%3D1%26%3B&sr_autoscroll=1&ss=Auckland&is_ski_area=0&ssne=Auckland&ssne_untouched=Auckland&city=-1506909&checkin_year=2020&checkin_month=9&checkin_monthday=1&checkout_year=2020&checkout_month=9&checkout_monthday=2&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&from_sf=1')
time.sleep(5)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll('label', {'class': "tpi_price_label tpi_price_label__orange"}):
    price.append(item.get_text(strip=True))
    print(price)
```

The above code is not showing any output. It gives an empty list.

Comment: That's probably because the website uses JavaScript to populate the content. In fact, I have found the request that spit out the details, `https://www.booking.com/fragment.en-gb.json?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEM2AEB6AEB-AELiAIBqAIDuALnhOzyBcACAQ;sid=3898211bdbd429da11d5ac635ef38152;srpvid=24ae14d7c54b006f&` into a JSON format response. You probably want to POST request that API link instead

Comment: are you  interested in the orange prices only or all prices

Comment: @HrisimirDakov only orange prices

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx how that works? can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need properly wait for the page to load.
This is done using WebDriverWait and it will throw exception if the page isnt loaded during the specified timeout.
Try running my sample code bellow:

```
# test_scrape.py
import atexit

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

URL = ("https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?"
       "label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEM2AEB6AEB-AELiAIBqAIDuALnhOzyBcACAQ"
       "&lang=en-gb&sid=422b3ff3c0e98b522259ad1cad2505ea&sb=1&src=searchresults&src_elem=sb"
       "&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Fsearchresults.en-gb.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-"
       "1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEM2AEB6AEB-AELiAIBqAIDuALnhOzyBcACAQ%3Bsid%3D422b3ff"
       "3c0e98b522259ad1cad2505ea%3Btmpl%3Dsearchresults%3Bclass_interval%3D1%3Bdest_id%3D-150690"
       "9%3Bdest_type%3Dcity%3Bdtdisc%3D0%3Bfrom_sf%3D1%3Bgroup_adults%3D2%3Bgroup_children%3D0%3"
       "Binac%3D0%3Bindex_postcard%3D0%3Blabel_click%3Dundef%3Bno_rooms%3D1%3Boffset%3D0%3Bpostcar"
       "d%3D0%3Braw_dest_type%3Dcity%3Broom1%3DA%252CA%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%3Bshw_aparth%3D1%3Bs"
       "lp_r_match%3D0%3Bsrc%3Dindex%3Bsrc_elem%3Dsb%3Bsrpvid%3D912403b6d1220012%3Bss%3DAuckland%3B"
       "ss_all%3D0%3Bssb%3Dempty%3Bsshis%3D0%3Bssne%3DAuckland%3Bssne_untouched%3DAuckland%3Btop_ufi"
       "s%3D1%26%3B&sr_autoscroll=1&ss=Auckland&is_ski_area=0&ssne=Auckland&ssne_untouched=Auckland&ci"
       "ty=-1506909&checkin_year=2020&checkin_month=9&checkin_monthday=1&checkout_year=2020&checkout_m"
       "onth=9&checkout_monthday=2&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&from_sf=1'")


class page_loaded:
    def __call__(self, driver):
        document_ready = driver.execute_script("return document.readyState;") == "complete"
        jquery_ready = driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0;")
        print(f"document ready: [({type(document_ready).__name__}){document_ready}]")
        print(f"jquery  ready: [({type(jquery_ready).__name__}){jquery_ready}]")
        return document_ready and jquery_ready


def wait_for_page_to_load(driver, timeout_seconds=20):
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout_seconds, 0.2).until(page_loaded(), f"Page could not load in {timeout_seconds} s.!")


def go_to_url(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)
    wait_for_page_to_load(driver)


def get_orange_prices(soup):
    return [price_label.get_text(strip=True)
            for price_label
            in soup.select("label.tpi_price_label.tpi_price_label__orange")]


def get_normal_prices(soup):
    return [price_label.get_text(strip=True)
            for price_label
            in soup.select("div[class*=bui-price-display__value]")]


def start_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    atexit.register(driver.quit)
    driver.maximize_window()
    return driver


def main():
    driver = start_driver()
    go_to_url(driver, URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    orange_prices = get_orange_prices(soup)
    print(orange_prices)
    normal_prices = get_normal_prices(soup)
    print(normal_prices)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you're having issues with the chromedriver not being discovered, try specify exact path to it like this:

```
def start_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/cromedriver")
    atexit.register(driver.quit)
    driver.maximize_window()
    return driver
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting this error "Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH" Even I added "driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())" in the code

Comment: @Jason Add the chromedriver (.exe) binary path into your system `PATH` environment variable